# What is the right method for parsing a blog post?

Tags: regex, parsing

Need a guide line ....
I am trying to write a personal blog.
What is the standard structure for for input for the post.
I am trying the format like:

```
This is the simple text
And I am [b] bold text[/b].
This is the code part:
[code lang=java]
public static void main (String args[]) {
   System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
[/code]
```

Is this the right way to store post in the database?

And What is the right method to parse this kind of post?
Shall I use regular expression to parse this or there is another standard for this.
If the above mentioned format is not the right way for storage, then what it could be?

Thanks

Comment: No standard at all. If it's your personal blog, do what you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me you are looking for something like [BBCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode)

Take a look on the link, there are several libraries that do this. One example (from Wikipedia):

- https://javabbcode.dev.java.net/

Disclaimer: Not tested myself

Also take a look on this question: [Java BBCode library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849396/java-bbcode-library)

**Edit:** Additional points

- From my experience BBCode is too weak for writing blog also its syntax is little bit annoying
- I would suggest go for Markdown - the same syntax Stackoverflow uses or even for reach text editor like TinyMCE - depending on what you are looking for.
- It is better to use one of the existing text formats as if you would like to migrate
  the content to other system it would be easier to find filters for this purpose.

Comment: Seems it might help. Thanks brother.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using an existing dialect like [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) or [textile](http://www.textism.com/tools/textile/)?
Both are feature rich in terms of supported markup, implementations are available in a plethora of languages, both for [markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown#Alternate_implementations) and [textile](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2007/05/praising_textile_1.html).

---

[1]: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

[2]: http://www.textism.com/tools/textile/

[3]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown#Alternate_implementations

[4]: http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2007/05/praising_textile_1.html

Answer (score 0):

XML is probably the best format for storing the post body, and there are many standard libraries for parsing it.