# Converting BB code to HTML for TextView

Tags: java, android, bbcode

I'm trying to convert BB code to HTML in Java for an Android project. An example of the text in which the bb code is embedded looks like this:

> [b]This[/b] is some [url="http://www.example.com"]example[/url] text
>   to display my problem.
>
> There also might be several paragraphs [i]of[/i] text and normal URLs http://www.example.com.

What it needs to look like in the TextView:

> **This** is some [example](http://www.example.com) text to display my problem.
>
> There also might be several paragraphs *of* text and normal URLs http://www.example.com.

Unfortunatly I don't have any code to show you since i don't know how to go about doing this. The only thing i can come up with now is making alot of regular expressions but i´m not sure if that would be the best solution.

Eventually this will all be displayed in an Android `TextView`.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some java BB-code libraries out there. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849396/java-bbcode-library) for information on them.

Comment: I guess you could also write it yourself, but it sounds like an awful lot of unnecessary work.