# Match BB Color code in android app/java

Tags: android, regex

If I want to match the following pattern like

`[black]something[/black]`
`[orange]something[/orange]`

and change them to HTML Code `<span style="color:black">something</span>`

But not change those not paired like `[black]hello[/orange]`

How can I write the regular expression to recognize them?

Comment: You want to parse only the BB color codes, or other BB codes as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java BBCode library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849396/java-bbcode-library)

Comment: @ShivanRaptor only BB color codes at this moment, some codes I have been parsed and some maybe parse it later.

Comment: Maybe you can look into the question I quoted above. They already found solution.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor But my BB color code is not written in `[color=black]something[/color]`, It written in `[black]blah blah[/black]` like this.

Comment: You can add few more cases to the solution.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor What I am going to ask is that how to write a regular expression that only match `[black]blah blah[/black]` but `[black]blah blah[/orange]`

Comment: Maybe you should try it yourself to change codes, instead of keep asking.

Comment: What regular expressions have you tried and what were the problems you encountered?

Comment: @dtmilano actually I wanna find out a regular expression which represent the same keywords like "black" must show up in correct position and twice only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution, as mentioned in comments:

```
public static String bbcode(String text) {
    String html = text;

    Map<String,String> bbMap = new HashMap<String , String>();

    bbMap.put("\\[black\\](.+?)\\[/black\\]", "<span style='color: black;'>$1</span>");
    bbMap.put("\\[orange\\](.+?)\\[/orange\\]", "<span style='color: orange;'>$1</span>");
    // add other colors

    for (Map.Entry entry: bbMap.entrySet()) {
        html = html.replaceAll(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString());
    }

    return html;
}
```

Comment: It seems that the second bbMap.put should be `\\[orange\\](.+?)\\[/orange\\]` right?

Answer (score 1):

Use KefirBB. It's configurable opensource library for text translations.

http://kefirsf.org/kefirbb/